# Create a new column evaluating values in different rows

Tags: python, pandas

Starting from an imported df from excel like that:

| Code | Time | Rev |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 5 | 3 |
| AAA | 3 | 2 |
| AAA | 6 | 1 |
| BBB | 10 | 2 |
| BBB | 5 | 1 |

I want to add a new column like that evidence the last revision:

| Code | Time | Rev | Last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 5 | 3 | OK |
| AAA | 3 | 2 | NOK |
| AAA | 6 | 1 | NOK |
| BBB | 10 | 2 | OK |
| BBB | 5 | 1 | NOK |

The df is already sorted by 'Code' and 'Rev'

```
df= df.sort_values(['Code', 'Rev'],
         ascending = [True,False])
```

I thought to evaluate the column 'Code', if the value in column Code is equal to the value in upper row I must have NOK in the new column.

Unfortunately, I am not able to write it in python

Comment: I'm thinking about changing all the second duplicate onwards with `df.unique` and then replacing them to "NOK". Or you can replace all to "NOK" first and then do `df.groupby("code"). nlargest` to get the first largest value and change it to "OK"

Comment: @user19613662  could you tell me why did you unmark my answer after you marked it as accepted?

Comment: Because also the other solution works and it seemed correct to me to reward the first. Just for that, also your solution works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
#Create a column called 'Last' with 'NOK' values
df['Last'] = 'NOK'

#Skipping sorting because you say df is already sorted.  

#Then locate the first row in each group and change its value to 'OK'
df.loc[df.groupby('Code', as_index=False).nth(0).index, 'Last'] = 'OK'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.groupby.cumcount and set every first row of group to 'OK'.

```
dict_ = {
    'Code': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB'],
    'Time': [5, 3, 6, 10, 5],
    'Rev': [3, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_)
df['Last'] = 'NOK'
df.loc[df.groupby('Code').cumcount() == 0,'Last']='OK'
```

This gives us the expected output:

```
df
  Code  Time  Rev Last
0  AAA     5    3   OK
1  AAA     3    2  NOK
2  AAA     6    1  NOK
3  BBB    10    2   OK
4  BBB     5    1  NOK
```

or you can try fetching the head of each group and set the value to `OK` for it.

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Code').head(1).index, 'Last'] = 'OK'
```

which gives us the same thing

```
df
  Code  Time  Rev Last
0  AAA     5    3   OK
1  AAA     3    2  NOK
2  AAA     6    1  NOK
3  BBB    10    2   OK
4  BBB     5    1  NOK
```